# Opening an AngularJS Modal from $watch

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use angularjs for a website in which a canvas item is clicked causing a bootstrap modal to open. So far I got everything else working except for a modal to appear. When the item is clicked I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Can someone help me figure why open is not being called correctly. Thank you much.

```
app.controller('contentModalCtrlr', ['$scope', function($scope, $modal) {
$scope.opened = '';

$scope.open = function (template) {
  consloe.log(template);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: template,
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlr',
        size: 'lg'
    });
};

$scope.$watch('opened', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue,oldValue);

    if (newValue == 'spellcards') {
        console.log('Open a Spell Card Modal!');
        $scope.open('spellcards.html');
    }
    else if (newValue == 'monstercards') {
  console.log('Open a Monster Card Modal!');
  $scope.open('monstercards.html');
}
}); 
console.log($scope);
}]);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo Error:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: template,
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlr', // <-- extra 'r'
    size: 'lg'
});
```

Should be

```
controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
```

Note:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/FK4nn7MtC2u6J51yOiaj?p=preview)

Comment: @deadpickle see my edit, Last night I was little tired and my answer was wrong. Fix it now.

Comment: You are right but I also forgot to pass (is that the right term) $modal in my contentModalCtrlr.